# import several rows from csv in R

Tags: r

I have csv file with N rows, where each row corresponds to a data point. Is there a way to just read a set of pre-specified rows from this csv file.

Comment: if they're contiguous, see `skip`, `nrows` arguments in `?read.csv` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is faster to extract the rows you want with another tool like Python or the Unix shell, but if R is your best choice:

```
file.in <- file('yourfile.txt', 'rt')
##file.header <- readLines(file.in,n=1) #do this if you are skipping a header
##change this to the lines that you want - line numbers must not decrease
ind.to.read <- c(10,15,20) 
##this is how many lines you want to skip in between lines you want
ind.to.skip <- c(ind.to.read[1],diff(ind.to.read)) - 1
# [1] 9 4 4 
##returns a list of data frames corresponding to rows
lines.to.keep <- lapply(ind.to.skip, function(x) { 
  readLines(file.in,n=x)
  read.table(file.in,nrow=1) 
}) 
small.df <- do.call(rbind,lines.to.keep) #put the data frames together
```

Answer (score 4):

You could specify the `skip` and `nrows` arguments to `read.csv`:

> `skip` integer: the number of lines of the data file to skip before beginning to read data.
>
> `nrows` integer: the maximum number of rows to read in. Negative and other invalid values are ignored.

Comment: For instance, the CSV file has 200 rows, I only need to read row 10, 20, 25, 26, 30,125, etc. How can I do that? Looks like skip and nrows cannot help me. Thanks.

Comment: @user785099: You're right. I unwittingly assumed you meant consecutive rows.